# Does `0 OP_CSV` force the spending transaction to signal BIP125 replacability?

Tags: replace-by-fee, sequence, checksequenceverify, bip-125-replaceable

If I send bitcoins to an output whose script will execute `0 OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY` when it is spent, does that require the spender to set the [BIP125](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0125.mediawiki) signal indicating that the transaction is replacable?

For example, in cases where participants in a contract protocol (like Lightning Network) wanted to ensure a transaction would signal it was replacable, could adding `0 OP_CSV` to all script branches provide that guarantee of replacability?

Additionally, would `0 OP_CSV` impose any additional requirements on the transaction executing that operation beyond it needing to signal replacability and having a transaction version number greater than 1?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, since the `OP_CSV` requires setting a non-maximal `nSequence` in the spending input, an input spending it is forced to signal replaceability.

Ruben Somsen mentions that he used this construction in his [Spacechains Proof of Concept](https://github.com/RubenSomsen/spacechains) and explains that it indeed enforces use of RBF (and permits the UTXO to be spent within the same block).

He points out that with the *anyone can spend* construction he was using, this would leave a 0 on the stack, which would fail the script evaluation. He worked around this issue by adding an `OP_1ADD` to the script.
Ruben suggests that this outcome is why Miniscript disallows timelocks of 0.

Source: [Tweet by Ruben Somsen](https://twitter.com/SomsenRuben/status/1683056160373391360)